Equivalent definitions for GO-spaces (generalized ordered spaces)
GO-spaces (= generalized ordered spaces) are subspaces of LOTS (linearly ordered topological spaces).  There are several definitions in use and I am wondering how to show the equivalence between them.
A subset $A$ of an ordered set $(X,<)$ is called order-convex if for each $a,b\in A$ with $a<b$, $A$ contains all points of $X$ between $a$ and $b$.

Proposition: Let $X$ be a topological space with topology $\tau$.  The following are equivalent:
(a) There is a linear order $<$ on $X$ such that $\tau$ contains the order topology induced by the order $<$ and every point has a local base of $\tau$-open nbhds consisting of order-convex sets.
(b) $X$ is $T_1$ and there is a linear order $<$ on $X$ such that every point has a local base of $\tau$-open nbhds consisting of order-convex sets.
(c) $X$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of a LOTS.

Below is a proof that (a) and (b) are equivalent.  Can someone provide a proof of the equivalence with (c)?

(a) implies (b):
Suppose $<$ is a linear order on $X$ as in condition (a).  The order topology induced by $<$ is $T_1$ (actually even $T_5$ as for any LOTS). The topology $\tau$ is finer than that order topology, hence also $T_1$.

(b) implies (a):
Suppose (b) holds.  The order topology induced by $<$ admits the collection of open rays $(\leftarrow,x)$ and $(x,\to)$ as a subbase.  So to show $\tau$ is finer than that order topology, it is enough to show that these rays are $\tau$-open.  Let $x\in X$.  Since $\{x\}$ is closed, the set $U=(\leftarrow,x)\cup(x,\to)$ is open.  Given $w<x$, there is some order-convex $\tau$-open nbhd $V$ of $w$ contained in $U$.  But since $V$ is order-convex and does not contain $x$, it cannot contain points to the right of $x$.  That is, $V\subseteq(\leftarrow,x)$, which shows that $(\leftarrow,x)$ is $\tau$-open.  And similarly for $(x,\to)$.

Additional observation:
Given (a) or (b), every point $x\in X$ admits a local base of $\tau$-open nbhds of a special form.
Every open interval $(a,b)$ with $a<x<b$ is $\tau$-open, since $\tau$ is finer than the order topology induced by $<$. Now, let $V$ be an order-convex nbhd of $x$.  If $V$ contains points of $X$ both to the left and to the right of $x$, it necessarily contains an open interval $(a,b)$ around $x$.  On the other hand, if $V$ contains no element of $X$ to the left of $x$, necessarily $V\subseteq[x,\to)$ and $[x,\to)$ is $\tau$-open (as the union of $V$ and $(x,\to)$).  Similarly, if $V$ contains no element of $X$ to the right of $x$, necessarily $V\subseteq(\leftarrow,x]$ and $(\leftarrow,x]$ is $\tau$-open.  Combining the various possibilities, it's easy to check that $V$ contains a $\tau$-open nbhd of $x$ having the form of an interval (open, half-open, or singleton interval) of the form $(a,b)$, $[x,b)$, $(a,x]$, or $[x,x]=\{x\}$ with $a<x$ and/or $x<b$ as the case may be.  So the order-convex sets in a local base at $x$ can be chosen to be intervals of that form.
To summarize, every point of $X$ has a local base of $\tau$-open nbhds of (possibly degenerate) intervals of $(X,<)$.
It also follows that a subbase for the topology $\tau$ is given by the collection of sets consisting of:

(1) all sets of the form $(\leftarrow,x)$ and $(x,\to)$ for $x\in X$;

(2) all sets of the form $(\leftarrow,x]$ such that $(\leftarrow,x]$ is $\tau$-open, $x$ is not the maximum element of $X$ and $x$ has no immediate successor in $(X,<)$;

(3) all sets of the form $[x,\to)$ such that $[x,\to)$ is $\tau$-open, $x$ is not the minimum element of $X$ and $x$ has no immediate predecessor in $(X,<)$.


Note that the sets in (1) generate the order topology on $X$ induced by $<$.  The cases (1), (2), (3) above are mutually exclusive.  A base for the topology is formed by finite intersections of sets in the subbase, which have the form of suitable open, half-open or closed intervals or rays in $(X,<)$.

Alternate characterizations:
Conditions (a) and (b) in the Proposition above were stated in terms of every point having a local base of $\tau$-open order-convex nbhds.  But using the same kind of reasoning as in the "Additional observation" above, it's easy to see that it's enough to have a local base of order-convex nbhds without requiring them to be open for the topology.
(For example, as one of the cases to be considered, supposed $V$ is a (not necessarily open) order-convex nbhd of $x$ with $V\subseteq[x,\to)$ and $V$ contains an element $b$ with $x<b$.  Then $[x,\to)$ is open in $X$, as the union of the open sets $\operatorname{int}(V)$ and $(x,\to)$.  As $(\leftarrow,b)$ is also open in $X$, so is their intersection $[x,b)$, which is a $\tau$-open order-convex nbhd of $x$ contained in $V$.  The other cases are handled similarly.)
To summarize:

In the Proposition above, conditions (a), (b), (c) are also equivalent to the following:
(d) There is a linear order $<$ on $X$ such that $\tau$ contains the order topology induced by the order $<$ and every point has a local base of order-convex nbhds.
(e) $X$ is $T_1$ and there is a linear order $<$ on $X$ such that every point has a local base of order-convex nbhds.


Have you checked this paper by D. J. Lutzer ?

thanks, I'll take a look.

(c) implies (b):
Let $Y$ be a LOTS, with order $<$ and corresponding order topology $\tau'$.  Let $X$ be a subset of $Y$, with subspace topology $\tau$ induced from $\tau'$, and with linear order equal to the restriction of the order on $Y$.
Since $Y$ is a LOTS, each point $x\in X$ has a local base of $\tau'$-open nbhds in $Y$ consisting of open intervals or open rays in $(Y,<)$, which are order-convex. Intersecting these with $X$ gives a local base of $\tau$-open nbhds of $x$ in $X$ that are order-convex in $(X,<)$.  In addition, $X$ is $T_1$ as a subspace of a $T_1$ space.

(a) implies (c):
Suppose (a) holds; that is, $(X,<)$ is a linearly ordered set and $\tau$ is a topology on $X$ containing the order topology induced by $<$ and every point has a local base of $\tau$-open nbhds consisting of order-convex sets.
As explained in the "Additional obervation" section of the question, $\tau$ has a subbase consisting of the sets satisfying (1), (2), or (3).  The sets in (1) form the usual subbase for the order topology on $X$ induced by $<$.
Now construct a larger ordered set $(Y,<)$ containing $X$ and extending the order on $X$ as follows.  For each set $(\leftarrow,x]$ in (2), add an element $x^+$ as an immediate successor to $x$.  And for each set $[x,\to)$ in (3), add an element $x^-$ as an immediate predecessor to $x$.  Let $\tau'$ be the order topology on $Y$ induced by this order, with makes $Y$ into a LOTS.
Claim: The subspace topology on $X$ induced by $\tau'$ coincides with $\tau$.
For convenience, let's write intervals in $Y$ with a subscript $Y$ and intervals in $X$ without subscript.  To show the claim, take the subbase for $(Y,\tau')$ consisting of all intervals $(\leftarrow,y)_Y$ and $(y,\to)_Y$ with $y\in Y$ and look at the intersection of each of them with $X$.  The different cases are, with $x\in X$ and $x^+$ and $x^-$ as defined above:

$X\cap(\leftarrow,x)_Y=(\leftarrow,x)$ and $X\cap(x,\to)_Y=(x,\to)$;
$X\cap(\leftarrow,x^+)_Y=(\leftarrow,x]$ and $X\cap(x^+,\to)_Y=(x,\to)$;
$X\cap(\leftarrow,x^-)_Y=(\leftarrow,x)$ and $X\cap(x^-,\to)_Y=[x,\to)$.

The subbase obtained for the subspace topology consists of all the sets satisfying conditions (1), (2), (3), which form a subbase for the topology $\tau$.

Notes:

It is easy to check that $X$ is a topologically dense subset of the LOTS $Y$.  Let $(Z,<)$ be the Dedekind-MacNeille completion of the ordered space $(Y,<)$.  The ordered set $Z$ is order-complete, so it is compact with its order topology.  It is a general fact that $Y$ is topologically dense in $Z$ with its order topology; so $X$ is also topologically dense in $Z$.  Thus every GO-space is homeomorphic to a dense subspace of a compact LOTS (such that the homeomorphism preserves the order).

The construction in the paper


Lutzer, David J., On generalized ordered spaces, Dissertationes Math., Warszawa 89, 32 p. (1971). ZBL0228.54026.
is a little different.  For case (2), instead of a successor $x^+$ after $x$, it adds a chain of successors, i.e., a copy of $\omega=\{1<2<3<\dots\}$. For case (3), instead of adding a predecessor $x^-$ before $x$, it adds a chain of predecessors, i.e., a copy of $\omega^*=\{\dots<-3<-2<-1\}$.  The resulting ordered set $(X^*,<)$ gives a LOTS that contains $X$ as a closed subspace.
